# Ошибка: conflict with dependency junit

Tags: java, android, junit

Вот сама ошибка:

> Error:Conflict with dependency 'junit:junit'. Resolved versions for
>   app (4.11) and test app (4.12) differ. See
>   http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.

Comment: Измените зависимость в pom файле или build.gradle. Измените версию библиотеки.

Answer (score 1):

Основной APK и тестовый APK используют общий classpath. Сборка падает по той причине, что в зависимостях у основного APK и тестового APK есть одна и та же библиотека, но версии библиотек разные. Если бы сборка не падала, то  приложение могло бы работать в режиме теста не так, как в обычном режиме.

Чтобы избавиться от данной ошибки, нужно поправить версии зависимостей, чтобы они были одинаковыми.

В тексте ошибки вас как раз направляют на данное объяснение: http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict